# File being used by another process, cannot be accessed

Tags: c#, wpf, logging

I am creating loggers to log messages to a text file. The function DeleteOldLogs() is responsible to delete any logs that are over 14 days old.
When I run TestMethod1(), I receive an error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"
Is there a way to avoid that error?

// TestClass

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    LoggerViewModel lv = new LoggerViewModel();
    lv.DeleteOldLogs();
}
```

// LoggerViewModel class.

```
[Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public class LoggerViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<LogItem> LogItems { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<LogItem> logItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();
        protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerViewModel));
        private string dirPath = @"C:\LogFolder";

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public LoggerViewModel()
        {
            MemoryAppender memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();

            BasicConfigurator.Configure(memoryAppender);
            Log();
            var events = memoryAppender.GetEvents();
            foreach (LoggingEvent loggingEvent in events)
            {
                LogItem logItem = new LogItem(loggingEvent.TimeStamp, loggingEvent.Level, loggingEvent.RenderedMessage);
                logItemCollection.Add(logItem);
            }
            LogItems = logItemCollection;
        }

        public void Log()
        {
            string stackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;
            string[] array = stackTrace.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string item in array)
            {
                log.Debug(item);
            }
        }

        public void DeleteOldLogs()
        {
            List<string> delPaths = new List<string>();
            foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(dirPath))
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                DateTime fileCreationDate = info.CreationTime;
                DateTime twoWeeksAgo = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-14);
                if (fileCreationDate < twoWeeksAgo)
                {
                    string delPath = dirPath + @"\" + info.Name;
                    delPaths.Add(delPath);
                }
            }
            foreach(string dp in delPaths)
            {
                FileSystem.DeleteFile(dp, UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The most frequantly reason of such Exception: another process opened this file (good day, captain). Did you open this file in notepad, Word, browser or other program?
Other variant - you write info to log, using one of Stream object and don't close\flush\dispose them. How does work 
log.Debug(item);
method?

I advise you to debug you test and to find the place that throws an exception.

Comment: No, I did not open the file in any program.

Comment: So, try to debug your test and find the code part that throws an error.

Comment: Try using process explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and search the processes using the file (FIle -> Find handle or DLL) Also I noticed FileSystem class is in Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly. I generally use System.IO and use File.Delete(path). It wouldn't solve your problem right away but I think it's more standard to use System.IO